# Intellij idea AS3 loading images

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, intellij-idea

I have a problem with displaying images in my AS3 application. I work in intellij idea and 
when I execute application from Idea it's ok. But when I am trying to execute swf file in out I see a application with white screen and nothing else.
When I execute this in browser, I see see only first menu but I cannot interact with it.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Side note: Have you heard of FlashDevelop?

Answer (score 0):

Place your flash application in the trusted location (place working folder where you store and develop as3 projects). I think It's your main problem

> For developers: Flash developers often work on SWF or FLV content that is eventually deployed on the Internet. During development of these applications, developers need to test while the SWF or FLV content is stored locally rather than deployed on a web server. For security, Flash Player blocks SWF and FLV content stored locally from accessing the Internet, and it prevents SWF and FLV content on the Internet from accessing your computer.

More information: how to set up you [will find here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlayer/LSM/WS6aa5ec234ff3f285139dc56112e3786b68c-7ff0.html#WS6aa5ec234ff3f285139dc56112e3786b68c-7fea).